# How to register ocx file using visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, ocx

How can I find if an ocx file (swf ocx file) is registered or not?

and if is registered which version is that?

and if is not registered how can I register that?

Answer (score 3):

### Regsvr32.exe

---

If you'll check the registry

**HKCR\CLSID{guidInQuestion}** you can determine if the OCX is registered.

To determine the **GUID** for your OCX:

- Open the OCX with **OleView.exe** (program-Files\Visual-studio\Tools)
- You will see something like -

> // Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
>   //
>   // typelib filename: COMDLG32.OCX
>   [
>   uuid(***F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB***),
>   version(1.2),
>   helpstring("Microsoft Common Dialog
>   Control 6.0 (SP3)"),
>   helpfile("cmdlg98.chm"),
>   helpcontext(0x00030d40)
>   ]

- Check if the ***GUID*** you obtained for your OCX exists in the registry.

  Use these functions to access the registry in code.
  **RegOpenKeyEx()** &
  **RegQueryValueEx()**

  > More info on them **[here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=4858)** (code sample)

---

You can use the Microsoft Register Server (Regsvr32.exe) to register a 32- bit .ocx file manually.

```
Regsvr32 /s <swf-ocx-file.OCX>
```

To execute Regsvr32.exe from code:

```
int x = (int)ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\regsvr32.exe", "/s <swf-ocx-file.OCX" , NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

> For more info on **Regsvr32.exe** refer:
>    -  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146219
>    -  http://support.microsoft.com/?id=207132
>
> For more info on **shellExecute()** refer:
>   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: hi
i use this code
int x = (int)ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\regsvr32.exe", "/s <swf-ocx-file.OCX" , NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

but ocx file did not register and 

i can't use swf file 

please help me

thanks

Comment: plz remove the <swf-ocx-file.OCX>. Those were place holders. Use the full path of the ocx file in its place. For example "D:\\project\\swf.ocx"

Answer (score 0):

You may do this manually using [this instruction from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=207132).